# Node.JS express app.use doesn't get called on image request

Tags: node.js, express

When images in `/uploads/private/` are requested, I want the client to supply a username/password to ensure that they have permission to view files in this directory. I have an `app.use` method here:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
if (req.user == null && req.path.indexOf('/uploads/private') === 0) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({status: 0, error: "Not authenticated"}));
    res.end();
    return;
} else {
    console.log(req.path);
}
next();
});
```

However, this isn't called when I request the image from my server, only when anything else is requested. How can I ensure this function is called when images are retrieved from this directory?

Comment: you should have it before all your routes

Comment: It was already before all of my routes.